# getInitialProps in _app prevents the getIitialProps from working in other pages

Tags: next.js

I'm new to Nextjs, and trying to make getInitialProps in _app.js work to check protected routes and get info about logged in user, and also use getInitialProps in other pages, but even with empty functions, the mere existence of getInitialProps in _app.js prevents getInitialProps to be called in another page:

_app.js:

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }) => {

  return {};
};
```

[profilePage].js :

```
ProfilePage.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  console.log("getting initial props");
  return {};
}; // This won't be called
```

How can I set up the two functions to work simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

In your `_app` file, you need to

```js
import App from "next/app"
```

and then in that same file in `getInitialProps` call

```js
const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext)
```

This will run `getInitialProps` on the individual pages. You'll want to pass `appProps` to the main component in `_app`.

```js
// _app.js
import App from "next/app"

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  // whatever your main _app component looks like here
  return (<Component { ...pageProps } />)
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }) => {
  // Stuff you want to do BEFORE loading props from the individual page

  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext)

  // Stuff you want to do AFTER loading props from the individual page

  return { ...appProps }
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: First thank you very much for your help, I'm working on it now and I think it should be Component.getInitialProps instead of App.getInitialProps. However if though with Component instead of App, the app will run, I'm still getting the error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
Do you know why?

Comment: I think I should create another question about this, thank you